# SSRS iIF statement -Looking for Nulls

Tags: reporting-services, null, switch-statement, expression, case

I am having a bit of a hard time writing a nested expression. I wish there was a tool to validate your expression for syntax :/

I have 5 columns.
Step
A1
B1
A2
B2

I need to check if:
The step is "Total" then make that grey. 
Otherwise if any of the other columns are NULL make them Blue.

I thought of making all the columns blue but conditionally change them to white if it was >0 but I still get tripped up on the multiple columns part

Can someone help or point me in the direction of an expression generator?

Thanks~

Comment: Grey...blue..white...can you please be a little clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a `Switch` expression for the **BackgroundColor** property, something like:

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Step.Value = "Total"
        , "Gray"
    , IsNothing(Fields!A1.Value)
            or IsNothing(Fields!A2.Value)
            or IsNothing(Fields!B1.Value)
            or IsNothing(Fields!B2.Value)
        , "Blue"
    , True
        , Nothing
    )
```

This worked for me against some simple data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit after comment**

To apply the `IsNothing` check by column, you will need to simplify the expression to check that column only, then change slightly for each column.

So for the *A1* column textbox it would be:

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Step.Value = "Total"
        , "Gray"
    , IsNothing(Fields!A1.Value)
        , "Blue"
    , True
        , Nothing
    )
```

And for the *A2* column textbox:

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Step.Value = "Total"
        , "Gray"
    , IsNothing(Fields!A2.Value)
        , "Blue"
    , True
        , Nothing
    )
```

Comment: Ian, Thanks! I tried the code but for me its highlighting the entire row vs highlighting just the Null cells.  I may not have explained this well.

Comment: For Total- The entire row should be highlighted in grey. For the others it would just be the null cell.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit based on the new information.